# Python.h: No such file or directory on Amazon Linux Lambda Container

Tags: docker, aws-lambda, pip, python-c-api, amazon-linux

I am trying to build this `public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.6` based Dockerfile with a requirements.txt file that contains some libraries that need gcc/g++ to build. I'm getting an error of a missing Python.h file despite the fact that I installed the python development package and `/usr/include/python3.6m/Python.h` exists in the file system.

Dockerfile

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.6
RUN yum install -y gcc gcc-c++ python36-devel.x86_64
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install cyquant
COPY app.py ./
CMD ["app.handler"]
```

When I build this with

```
docker build -t redux .
```

I get the following error

```
cyquant/dimensions.cpp:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
 #include "Python.h"
                    ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

Notice, however, that my Dockerfile yum installs the development package. I have also tried the yum package `python36-devel.i686` with no change.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Any luck? because I am stuck here too :(

Comment: I ended up just using a python image as my base instead of the lambda specific one.

Comment: So any image can be used for lambda, we are not supposed to stick with this?

Comment: Yeah I just used a regular Python image and add
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/python", "-m", "awslambdaric"]
CMD ["main.handler"]
And you need to pip install awslambdaric

Comment: Great, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to duplicate the behavior of the AWS Lambda functionality without their Docker image and it works just fine. This is the Dockerfile I am using.

```
ARG FUNCTION_DIR="/function/"

FROM python:3.6 AS build
ARG FUNCTION_DIR
ARG NETRC_PATH
RUN echo "${NETRC_PATH}" > /root/.netrc
RUN mkdir -p ${FUNCTION_DIR}
COPY requirements.txt ${FUNCTION_DIR}
WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --target ${FUNCTION_DIR} awslambdaric && \
    pip install --target ${FUNCTION_DIR} --no-warn-script-location -r requirements.txt

FROM python:3.6
ARG FUNCTION_DIR
WORKDIR ${FUNCTION_DIR}
COPY --from=build ${FUNCTION_DIR} ${FUNCTION_DIR}
COPY main.py ${FUNCTION_DIR}
ENV MPLCONFIGDIR=/tmp/mplconfig
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/python", "-m", "awslambdaric"]
CMD ["main.handler"]
```

Answer (score 2):

The `pip` that you're executing lives in `/var/lang/bin/pip` whereas the python you're installing lives in the `/usr` prefix

presumably you could use `/usr/bin/pip` directly to install, but I'm not sure whether that works correctly with the lambda environment

Comment: I think you're on to something here but I'm pretty sure the container is going to run /var/lang/bin/python for the actual Lambda execution. So perhaps I need to find the devel package for that python? It really doesn't seem to exist anywhere in the yum search.

Comment: there isn't one as far as I can tell -- a workaround would be to build wheels using the system python and then install those.  something like `/usr/bin/pip wheel -r requirements.txt -w wheels && pip install -r requirements.txt --no-index --find-links file://$PWD/wheels`